# Is it possible to use multiple version of php in different directory in apache?

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos

I would like to use 2 php versions on same domain is it possible ?

http://www.example.com -> php 5

http://www.example.com/newphp -> php7

and how?

I'm using Centos 6x

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, its possible you can install `5.6` and `7.0`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible with PHP-FPM, but not out of the box, as far as I know. You will have to do some compiling from source, and then some fancy Apache configuration. I can point you to an internet resource to get you started, but be aware this is not a task for the inexperienced.

The basic steps to compile PHP-FPM and Apache on CentOs are described in the first part of this tutorial:

https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-build-php-5.6-fpm-fastcgi-with-zend-opcache-and-apcu-for-ispconfig-3-on-debian-7-wheezy

You can install a second PHP-FPM version the same way you installed the first, and then configure which PHP pool you want to use in your Apache config or .htaccess files.

Comment: thank you I will try and let you know if it success.